# Capture image and voice(use AS3) in flv, save to location, not media server

Tags: actionscript-3, camera

How can I use AS3 to record video(with voice) by camera? I want it to be saved to location PC of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [flvRecorder](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/), but what they declare :

> The class does not yet support adding sound to the flv-file, this is the next step of development, to enable sound recording and add sound to the flv-file.

and it saves the file directly on the desktop, [check the example](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/wiki/HowToUseExample).

---

[This may be a solution too,](http://www.technogumbo.com/tutorials/Recording-Decent-Quality-Video-And-Audio-With-Flash-and-Red5/) that will allow you to record video/sound, give it a try,

Good luck, Cheers !!

Comment: i just follow the [How To Use Example](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/wiki/HowToUseExample)，it seems have some problems, perhaps I used it by the wrong way，i will continue study it. tks again!